# jquery fadein() is being called after all jquery function tranactions are completed?

Tags: jquery, fadein

i have a submit button that , when the user hits the submit button i want to fire up a Div with fadein() in jquery,  from the same function im calling another function called monthlyReport() , but this fadein div is being called after the montlyReport is called and its functionality is over

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
        $("#loading").fadeIn();
        monthlyReport($(this));
    });
});


function monthlyReport(Obj1) {

  //some transactions

  alert('test');

}
```

```
<div id="loading">
<div id="loadingcontent">
    <p id="loadingspinner">
        Searching things...
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

my requirement here is that  $("#loading").fadeIn(); should fire first and then monthlyReport() can continue with its transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the monthlyReport call to happen once the fadeIn() function has finished:

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
        var self = this;
        $("#loading").fadeIn('slow', function() {
           monthlyReport($(self));
        });
    });
});

function monthlyReport(Obj1) {    
  //some transactions

  alert('test');    
}
```

**EDIT :** Modified code to set the variable `self` to be the value of this in the click handler.

Comment: this is working fine but, when i use Obj1.Id  im getting the Id of the Div, but i need the Id of the clicked row details

Comment: How can i see that the values of the user clicked row are not lost

Comment: Modified my code, if you use the variable `self` by setting it to be the `this` object of the click handler you should be able to see the values of the button correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitbtn").on('click', function () {
        $("#loading").fadeIn('slow', function() {
           monthlyReport($(this));
        });
    });
});

function monthlyReport(Obj1) {    
  //some transactions

  alert('test');    
}
```

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?